# Image hover effect expanding outside container

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I currently have a grid of images with a 'greyscale to colour' and 'zoom' effect applied. The zoom effect is expanding outside the container. I have applied `overflow: hidden` (a couple of times) and set a `max-width`. However, these attempts have been unsuccessful. Here is my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RArnone/ut552b82/17/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <ul class="rows">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style=" float:left"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="50%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.rows {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.rows li a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rows a img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
}

.rows a img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  filter: grayscale(0) opacity(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container of images is `a` tag, so you should set `overflow: hidden` on this element:

```
.rows li a {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add above code to your css and set all your images width in html to `100%`:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Case Study" width="100%" height="auto" style="float:left"></a>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the explanation as well.